# Google Analytics Management API :: Create New View (Enable Enhanced Ecommerce settings

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer

Trying API Explorer https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/insert as per settings in attach screenshot.

The New GA View that's created has Ecommerce settings enabled (as expected) but Enhanced Ecommerce toggle still switched off... is it a Bug ? (also tried with Python Client Libraries, and same result...)

Thanks for clarification!

[image]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected. enhancedECommerceTracking can't be set on insert. See the reference documentation for [profiles/enhancedECommerceTracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles). You'll have to do an additional patch or update to set enhancedECommerceTracking.

From the reference page:

> enhancedECommerceTracking boolean Indicates whether enhanced ecommerce tracking is enabled for this view (profile). This property can only be enabled if ecommerce tracking is enabled. **This property cannot be set on insert.**

Answer (score 0):

I confirm I get the same behaviour. And if I [query the view back](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/get), the `enhancedECommerceTracking` property isn't even returned (`eCommerceTracking` is and is properly set to `true`). So it looks like a bug indeed. To be honest the management API is a bit shitty: I've seen other inconsistent values being returned, and the main problem is that you can't really automate account management since it's missing many features (eg even if there was no bug for `enhancedECommerceTracking`, you would still have to configure the funnel manually as it's not supported by the API).